# CSRF Synchronized Token

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

In the synchronized token pattern I always see the CSRF token in a hidden field or the URL. Is it safe to attach it to the end of an ajax post request and let the server decide if needs to use it? If it is why do people not do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it does not matter how you send the token in the synchronizer token pattern as long as it is not automatically sent by the browser if the request is made by another origin (ie. it's not in a cookie). So it's fine to "attach it to the end of an ajax post request" (although I'm not quite sure what you mean by that :) ).

When talking about a traditional forms applications without ajax calls, a hidden form field is the most convenient way. You just put the token in the hidden field for each form and there's nothing else to do on the client, easy.

Ajax changes the landscape, ajax calls don't automatically transmit the token, you have to take care of it automatically. For example with jQuery, you would use the `beforeSend` hook in `$.ajaxSetup` to automatically add the token to requests. When the request content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can just add it as another form variable, when it is a json request with `application/json`, you could add it as a json value. That would be secure, but I can see two problems.

One is that the token is kind of "metadata" for the request, not part of your business logic and business data. Also it is a cross-cutting concern across your data structures, not specific to queries. So it's better to keep it out of data structures.

The other problem is that adding the token to an already contructed request data in `beforeSend` is tedious. You have to dig into the data structure, find/cretae a variable for the token, etc.

It is much easier to just send it as a token, and that's what people mostly do when adding the token to ajax requests. Adding a custom request header like `X-CSRF-Token` or similar is very common, and the server side can then verify the token from there.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I have a non traditional way to do it in PHP. It's not common knowledge because it was designed specifically for by me for my application. I was just wondering if there was any security concerns I do not have very much knowledge in correcting securing an applications and what are some obvious or not so obvious flaws.